# Explain this particular python lambda expression

Tags: python, lambda

Iam trying to learn lambda expressions and came across the below :

```
funcs = {
        idx: lambda: print(idx) for idx in range(4)
        }

funcs[0]()
```

did not understand what is meant by funcs[0] ? Why the index and 0 ?

Comment: It means execute the function at key `0` of `funcs`. The variable `funcs` references a dictionary where the keys are integers, hence the `[0]`.

Comment: That has nothing to do with lambda expressions. It's just accessing a dictionary.

Comment: @chepner: What? Why would it be a KeyError?

Comment: @user2357112 I misread the dictionary comprehension; ignore my (now-deleted) comment.

Comment: (It's probably not doing what the author intended, unless the author intended it as a demonstration of closure variable lookup rules, but it's not a KeyError.)

Comment: The example shows different things: 1) building a dictionary from a loop (which is common in python), 2) You can build a dictionary of anything, so you may find useful to build a dictionary of functions : `funcs[0]()` means call the function corresponding to key 0. 3) It shows some of the problems of lazy evaluation (which `lambda` does), when you based a function on a scope variable inside a loop. In this case, the `lambdas` will always print the last value of `idx` (3), even if `idx` does not exist in the global scope (you cannot access it or edit it outside the loop)

Answer (score 0):

This is a cool example to show how binding and scope work with lambda functions. As Daniel said, `funcs` is a dictionary of functions with four elements in it (with keys 0,1,2 and 3). What is interesting is that you call the function at key 0, you expect the index (`idx`) that was used to create that key to then print out and you'll get 0. BUT I believe if you run this code, you actually print 3! WHAT!?!? So what is happening is that the lambda function is actually not binding the value of 0 when it stores the reference to the function. That means, when the loop finishes, the variable `idx` has 3 associated with it and therefore when you call the lambda function in position 0, it looks up the reference to the variable `idx` and finds the value `3` and then prints that out. Fun :)

That was referring more to your question title than to the test... The 0 is to access the function that has key 0 in the dictionary.